# iPhone Popup Confirmation

Tags: iphone

What pattern or view do you use to get the confirmation popup like in Mail where you are prompted to Reply, Forward or Cancel?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[UIActionSheet](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html).